# Customer Account Data API and UpdateAccountType method

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

In reference to the Customer Account Data API, is there a test login for CC Bank that will give back an account with a type marked as "Other" so that the UpdateAccountType service method can be tested?

I've seen this page, but none of these appear to meet my needs.
[Testing Calls to the API](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api)

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently do not have any test accounts under CC Bank that will allow you to test the updateAccountType call (they are all concrete account types).  I will raise this as an enhancement request for CC Bank.